# Spark:What is the ideal number of reducers

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

My data is about 300G. If I perform a reduce job on it using Hadoop, 180 reduce slots is ok and no task waits in the queue.

If I do it using Spark with the same num of reduce slots, it gets stuck during the shuffle stage while this would not happen if I use much more slots, let's say 4000, but this will end in low efficiency.

Is there anything I can do, such as tuning parameter, so that I can use the same slots as hadoop?

BTW, my cluster has 15 nodes and each nodes has 12 cores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shuffle Operation in Hadoop and Spark](http://analyticsindiamag.com/shuffle-operation-hadoop-spark/) is a nice read on the topic. Some quotes:

> Each map task in Spark writes out a shuffle file (operating system disk buffer) for every reducer – this corresponds to a logical block in Spark. These files are not intermediary in the sense that Spark does not merge them into larger partitioned ones. Since scheduling overhead in Spark is much lesser, the no. of mappers (M) and reducers(R) is far higher than in Hadoop. Thus, shipping M*R files to the respective reducers could result in significant overheads.
>
> A major difference between Hadoop and Spark is on the reducer side – Spark requires all shuffled data to fit into memory of the corresponding reducer task (we saw that Hadoop had an option to spill this over to disk).
>
> It does look like Hadoop shuffle is much more optimized compared to Spark’s shuffle from the discussion so far. However, this was the case and researchers have made significant optimizations to Spark w.r.t. the shuffle operation. The two possible approaches are 1. to emulate Hadoop behavior by merging intermediate files 2. To create larger shuffle files 3. Use columnar compression to shift bottleneck to CPU.

In [Optimizing Shuffle Performance in Spark](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ekubitron/courses/cs262a-F13/projects/reports/project16_report.pdf) similar conclusions are reached:

> By identifying the shuffle phase bottlenecks specific to Spark,
> we have explored several alternatives to mitigate the operating
> system overheads associated with these bottlenecks. The most fruitful of which is shuffle file consolidation, a
> simple solution that led to a 2x improvement in overall job
> completion time.

So you see, Hadoop/YARN does not compare directly to Spark, specially when it comes to shuffle and reduce. Spark requires specific optimization techniques, different from Hadoop. What *exactly* is needed in your case is difficult to guess. But my impression is that you're only skimming the surface of the issue and simply adjusting the number of reducers in Spark will not solve the problem.